# Lorentz boost property of gamma matrices

Tags: special-relativity, dirac-equation, spinors, dirac-matrices

I was watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5p4ZMrooSvw) where he boosted the Dirac equation. He reached this equation:

$$S^{-1}(\Lambda)\gamma^\mu S(\Lambda)=\Lambda^\mu{}_\nu \gamma^\nu$$

My question is since $\gamma^\mu$ is a column of matrices, what do the operators on the LHS operate on? The matrices themselves? And on the RHS, the "vector" itself?

What I understood for it is that transforming each matrix with $S(\Lambda)$ is the same as jumbling up the vectors in a specific way. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is since $\gamma^\mu$ is a column of matrices, what do the operators on the LHS operate on?
> The matrices themselves? And on the RHS, the "vector" itself?

The operators on the LHS (each of the $\gamma^\mu$, $S(\Lambda)$
and $S^{-1}(\Lambda)$) are complex $4\times 4$ matrices.
They operate on [Dirac spinors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_spinor) (usually written as $\psi$),
which are column "vectors" with $4$ complex components.

On the RHS each of the $\gamma^\nu$ is a complex $4\times 4$ matrix again.
And each of the $\Lambda^\mu{}_\nu$ is just a real number.
Hence the whole thing on the right ($\Lambda^\mu{}_\nu \gamma^\nu$)
is also a complex $4\times 4$ matrix,
and it operates on Dirac spinors again.

> What I understood for it is that transforming each matrix with $S(\Lambda)$ is the same
> as jumbling up the vectors in a specific way. Is this correct?

Yes.
Transforming a single matrix $\gamma^\mu$ with the matrix $S$
is the same as taking the linear combination of the matrices
$\gamma^0, \gamma^1, \gamma^2, \gamma^3$
with the coefficients $\Lambda^\mu{}_\nu$.